# Attempting to pass a list of objects using ajax to my controller yields null data

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, .net-core

I'm passing a list of objects in JSON to my controller, the communication appears to be working but the data coming into my controller that I am passing is coming up null.  I've scoured so many different posts, all pointing to similar issues that I've adjusted and tried different methods.  This is my
**JS Code:**

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dentalCaseList = {
            DentalCases: []
    };
    
    $("tr[class*=dentalCase]").each(function (index, e) {
        let dentalCase = {
            Date: "",
            UnitCount: 0,
            UnitType: "",
            Name: "",
            FullPath: "",
        };

        dentalCase.Name = $(this).find(".unitName").html(),
        dentalCase.UnitType = $(this).find(".select-unit").val(),
        dentalCase.UnitCount = parseInt($(this).find(".unitCount").html())

        dentalCaseList.DentalCases.push(dentalCase);
    });

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(dentalCaseList);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DentalCase/GenerateReport",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dentalCaseList),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Data received: ');
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
        
});
```

This is my Controller:

```
using DentalManager.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DentalManager.Controllers
{
    public class DentalCaseController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GenerateReport([FromBody] DentalCaseList dentalCaseList)
        {
            //Creating List    
            List<DentalCase> ObjEmp = new List<DentalCase>()
            {    
                //Adding records to list    
                new DentalCase {Name="Testing Tester",UnitCount=1,UnitType=UnitType.Default },
                new DentalCase {Name="Banana",UnitCount=2,UnitType=UnitType.Default }
            };
            //return list as Json    
            return Json(ObjEmp);
        }
    }
}
```

**dentalCaseList is coming in null**

this is my model:

```
namespace DentalManager.Model
{
    public class DentalCase
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Date")]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("UnitCount")]
        public int UnitCount { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("UnitType")]
        public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("FullPath")]
        public string? FullPath { get; set; }
    }

    public enum UnitType
    {
        Default = 0,
        FullDesign = 1,
        Implant = 2
    }

    public class  DentalCaseList
    {
        public List<DentalCase> DentalCases { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've attempted name changes, including FromBody attributes, JsonPropertyName attributes, removing nullable types, double and triple checking property names.  I just don't get what I'm missing.  I apologize if this is a poor post, it's my first one.  But I'm just struggling and I feel like it's something silly I'm missing.

Comment: You need to determine if issue is in client or server.  The json is in the body of the request.  Is the controller in the client or server?  Is the json going into the request or the response?  It looks like you are adding json to body but you have [FromBody]  Try removing [FromBody]

Comment: @jdweng The Json I'm having an issue with is in the request, in the browser, I can see my  data is there upon building the object.  With that being said, I removed the [FromBody] from the controller, and that actually did yield me an empty object(not null), but the "DentalCases" list is now null.  So I'll keep looking.  But here's an example of what I'm sending: 
'{"DentalCases":[{"Date":"","UnitCount":1,"UnitType":"Default","Name":"Adams_L10_72745_20230717_1531","FullPath":""},{"Date":"","UnitCount":1,"UnitType":"Default","Name":"Alverez_Q65_72745_20230718_1133","FullPath":""}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add an enum serializer to Json.Text serializer. Fix your startup code

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
   o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});

// or maybe services.Add...
```

and your json string has Date:"", that is not valid for this property

```
 public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

fix your json string Date:null, or change a Date property to string, or create a custom serializer for a Date property

Comment: Thank you so much @Serge!  I have been going down SOOO MANY rabbit holes, I never once found this solution with the enum serializer.  Thank you thank you thank you, it works!